# How does include() work?

Tags: php, include

I was looking at some topics that is talking about my question but couldn't find or understand my specifics.

I have users, I want redirect that user to a website outside my web, stay there for 10 seconds, and then click a button that confirms that he has waited those seconds. I was thinking doing that like this :

```
<div id="shown_box_at_top"> you have to wait <div id="timer">10</div> more seconds. </div>

<div id="shown_box_after_timer"> <a href="confirm.php">Please click here</a></div>

<?php include('www.wesite.com');?>
```

Of course it's just an example but if I do it this way, and `www.website.com` have a visitor counter, the counter will add him as a visitor or not? Or maybe there is a better way to do it?

Comment: Hi there. If you could try to avoid all-lower-case when writing, that is often appreciated - it means less work to improve posts. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to redirect the user to this external website, you can use PHP header function to do something like this :

```
header('Location: http://www.example.com/');
```

However, once the user clicks on this link, you will lose control over that user as he won't be on your website anymore. I think the better way to do this would be to use iframes to display the external website on your own webpage. The user will increment the external page's visitor counter and since the user will be on your web-page, you will still have control over this user to do what you want after (let's say) 10 seconds using jQuery.

Comment: lol at first i was thinking you haven't read my question, but then i saw the answer, so if i'll use iframe, the external page will act the same way as he should?

Comment: Yes, when you open a page in an i-frame, it acts as an independent web-page (like one you would open in a tab) which is embedded into your webpage.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, `include` executes the HTML as php code locally, which is definitely not what you want, as it would create a `security vulnerability`. Instead, if at all, you want [`file_get_contents`](http://php.net/file_get_contents). Even better, consider using an [iframe](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/iframe) so that the website gets downloaded from the client.

Comment: ok, but the question is, if i'll use file_get_contents, it will be just the same like i'm on `www.website.com`? so it will count that user as a visitor on his page right?

Comment: No, it will generally neither have the same experience. It depends on how the counter is implemented.